# re-use variable from another class file to AppWidget Android

Tags: android, class, variables, android-appwidget

everyone, i've a little problem how to use variable from another class file to App Widget.

Here, my little sourcecode :

TimeKu.Java :

```
public class TimeKu extends Activity {
private ListView lvUsers;
private ArrayList<UserAP> mListUsers;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  .....            

}

public ArrayList<UserAP> getUsers(){                

    DBAdapter dbAdapter=DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
    try {
        dbAdapter.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
    }
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();
    //query langsung ke database di sistem buat perbandingan
    String query="SELECT * FROM ********** WHERE date(tanggal) = date('now')";
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
    dbAdapter.close();

    ArrayList<UserAP> usersList = new ArrayList<UserAP>();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
        UserAP user = new UserAP();
        try {
            user.tanggal = list.get(1);
            user.xyz = list.get(2);
            user.abc = list.get(3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("***" + TimeKu.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
        usersList.add(user);
    }
    return usersList;
}

    // ***ListAdapter***
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserAP> { 
    private ArrayList<UserAP> mList; 
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<UserAP> list) { // --CloneChangeRequired
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.mList = list;
        this.setmContext(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        try{
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);    
        }
        final UserAP listItem = mList.get(position);                
        if (listItem != null) {
            // konfigurasi list view dari konten di database                        
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tgl) ).setText( listItem.getTanggal()+"");
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.xyz) ).setText( listItem.getXYZ()+"");
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.abc) ).setText( listItem.getABC()+"");

        }}catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TimeKu.ListAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());             
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void setmContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public Context getmContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

}
```

}

And HelloWidget.Java :

```
 public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    ArrayList<UserAP> list = null;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, list, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
}

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    private ArrayList<UserAP> mList; 

    public MyTime(Context context, ArrayList<UserAP> list, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        this.mList = list;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.sholatwidget);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, HelloWidget.class);
    }

    public void run() {
        final UserAP listItem = mList.get(0); 
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.xyz,
                "" + **[I Want to Call listItem.getXYZ() Here from TimeKu.Java. How?]**);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

}
 }
```

On public void run() in HelloWidget.Java, i want to call/use listItem.getXYZ() from TimeKu.Java with same result. How?
Very great Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Widy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea for one class to have access to members of another class without very good reason.

Comment: how it's bad? any advice, please? :)

Comment: The purpose of a class is to encapsulate certain variables and methods to represent an object. If another class is accessing members of another class, then the whole purpose of it is lost. Of course, there are exceptions, but generally speaking the best designs have well-modularized code.

Comment: Can you help me, how the way to put same result HelloWidget.Java like TimeKu.Java? Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific please.

Comment: owh, sorry. I've TimeKu.Java that results list for my task today. My task content i've got from SQLite Database. So it's works. But, when i try to create that on AppWidget...i try to call all that i needed on TimeKu.Java, for purpose to gain same result as TimeKu.Java. But it doesn't work :( Any best solution?

Comment: Or any another solution how to use my app's contents to my widget?